# Rmarkdown calls different Python than bash

Tags: python, r, bash, r-markdown

I am trying to call a Python script from within Rmarkdown. The script relies on Biopython but this library is not found if called from rmarkdown

**from Rmarkdown**

````
```{r, engine = "bash"}
python --version
```
````

> Python 2.7.10

**from the bash shell**

```
python --version
```

> Python 2.7.12

How can I control which version is called?

(I recall having installed a different python version with homebrew which might have led to this mess...)

Comment: You can use python directly (instead of using bash engine): ```{python, engine='python2', engine.path='<path to python version 2.12>'}```

Comment: yes, but the I have a python script that I want to call with arguments ```python myscript.py arg1 arg2```

Comment: I managed to find the python version that is called from the shell, it is under ```/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python``` so I can call it directly with the full path. But why doesn't Rmarkdown call the default python? Also: the script fails anyway because it seems to get confused with the paths

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `engine.path` variable in your chunk. If you are using Anaconda, it might look like this...

````
```{python, engine.path="~/anaconda3/bin/python"}
your code here...
```
````

When you are running the correct python in your terminal you can run...

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

This should point you to the location of the python executable you should pass as an argument to `engine.path` in RMarkdown/knitr.